# CSS transition animation causes residual border lines on the page

Tags: css

I made a pop-up window and used transition animation in CSS.
When I open the pop-up window, there is no problem with the transition animation, but when the pop-up window is closed, there will be residual border lines on the page.
This happens in Google Chrome.
[image]
Please click here for details：
https://codepen.io/lianflower/pen/zYKRPJb

```
<button data-modal-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="title">Example Modal</div>
        <button data-close-button class="closebutton">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        A wiki (/ˈwɪki/ (About this soundlisten) WIK-ee) is a hypertext publication collaboratively edited and managed by its own audience directly using a web browser. A typical wiki contains multiple pages for the subjects or scope of the project and may be either open to the public or limited to use within an organization for maintaining its internal knowledge base
    </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

```
*，*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.modal.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header .title {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```
var openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
var closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget);
        openModal(modal)
    })
});

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var modal = button.closest('.modal');
        closeModal(modal)
    })
});

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active');
    modals.forEach(modal => {
        closeModal(modal)
    });
});

function openModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return;
    modal.classList.add('active');
    overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closeModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return;
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

Comment: Try the below code. You will no longer have these extra borders :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modal has a border,   `border: 1px solid black;` That is causing this thing to happen. Put border on `modal.active` class instead and you are good to go.

**Update:** Set your borders only when the modal is active on any of the children components of modal in order to avoid these extra lines.

Codepen:https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/MWjQrJd

**Full Code:**

```js
var openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
    var closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget);
            openModal(modal)
        })
    });

    closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var modal = button.closest('.modal');
            closeModal(modal)
        })
    });

    overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active');
        modals.forEach(modal => {
            closeModal(modal)
        });
    });

    function openModal(modal) {
        if (modal == null) return;
        modal.classList.add('active');
        overlay.classList.add('active')
    }

    function closeModal(modal) {
        if (modal == null) return;
        modal.classList.remove('active');
        overlay.classList.remove('active')
    }
```

```css
*，*::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal { /* Removed border from is selector */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.modal.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  border: 1px solid black; /*--- Added border here ---*/
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header .title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.modal-body.active{ /* Add border on active class only */
 border:1px solid blue;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<button data-modal-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="title">Example Modal</div>
    <button data-close-button class="closebutton">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        A wiki (/ˈwɪki/ (About this soundlisten) WIK-ee) is a hypertext publication collaboratively edited and managed by its own audience directly using a web browser. A typical wiki contains multiple pages for the subjects or scope of the project and may be either open to the public or limited to use within an organization for maintaining its internal knowledge base
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: This solution is not ideal.
If I add a red border to the .modal-body, after closing the pop-up window, there will still be residual border lines on the page, but this time it is red.
https://codepen.io/lianflower/pen/vYXdpde

Comment: Modal-Body you are saying :) Let me see @Lotus

Comment: This method can be used, but I don’t know if there is a better solution. @Imran Rafiq Rather

Comment: In fact, I think this may be a browser compatibility issue because there is no such issue on Firefox. Can this problem be solved from the compatibility aspect? @Imran Rafiq Rather

Comment: As long as Modal goes :) We don't have many things within to show, A modal with some information and that's it. May be a action button. Hence, We can go with the fix that I have provided.  When you say compatibility aspect we may try browser prefixes on border property.. But I think as part of testing it is already fixed for Chrome by showing borders only when the modal is open in  other words active